# ConversationHandler not moving to the next state

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I have the following ConversationHandler

```
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('entry' entry)],
        states={
            ONE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, one)],
            TWO: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, two)],
            THREE: [CallbackQueryHandler(three)],
            FOUR: [CallbackQueryHandler(four)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler(Commands.CANCEL.value, cancel)],
    )
```

I defined the states keys as follows:
`ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR = range(4)`

Entry function:

```
async def entry(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text("bla")
    return ONE
```

ONE function:

```
async def one(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> int:
    x = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text("yes. bla.")
    context.user_data["x"] = x
    return TWO
```

TWO function:

```
async def two(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text("bla")
    keyboard = [
        ['7', '8', '9'],
        ['4', '5', '6'],
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['0']
    ]

    await update.message.reply_text("bla", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    context.user_data["x"] = query.data
    return THREE
```

The transition between the entry function to ONE works, but the next transition between ONE and TWO doesn't.

While debugging, when I am about to return ONE, the object `self.map_to_parent` is None so I suppose there was somewhat of a parsing error (?) in the ConversationHandler but I can't find it.

Additional info:

- No errors displayed
- python-telegram-bot = "==20.0a1"

---

EDIT:

I fixed function's TWO keyboard and removed the usage of the callback_query

```
async def two(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text("bla")
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('7'), InlineKeyboardButton('8'), InlineKeyboardButton('9')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('4'), InlineKeyboardButton('5'), InlineKeyboardButton('6')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('1'), InlineKeyboardButton('2'), InlineKeyboardButton('3')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('0')],
    ]

    await update.message.reply_text("bla", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

    return THREE
```

Still, the transition between ONE and TWO doesn't work, no errors but I did get a warning:

```
PTBUserWarning: If 'per_message=False', 'CallbackQueryHandler' will not be tracked for every message. Read this FAQ entry to learn more about the per_* settings: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-do-the-per_-settings-in-conversationhandler-do.
  conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
```

---

EDIT 2

Minimal example :

```
import os

from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
    CommandHandler,
    Application,
    ContextTypes,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
    ConversationHandler,
)
BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")
ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR = range(4)


async def entry(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text("entry_bla")
    return ONE


async def one(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> int:
    x = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text("yes. bla.")
    context.user_data["x"] = x
    return TWO


async def two(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text("two_bla")
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('7'), InlineKeyboardButton('8'), InlineKeyboardButton('9')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('4'), InlineKeyboardButton('5'), InlineKeyboardButton('6')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('1'), InlineKeyboardButton('2'), InlineKeyboardButton('3')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('0')],
    ]

    await update.message.reply_text("bla", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

    return THREE


async def cancel(update: Update, context: ContextTypes):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = Application.builder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('entry', entry)],
        states={
            ONE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, one)],
            TWO: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, two)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
    )

    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
    application.run_polling()
```

Comment: Did you read the faq entry? ;)

Comment: @CallMeStag I did, but I didn't actually think it is related to the bug here.
In any case, the warning message doesn't appear in the minimal example

Answer (score 0):

With your code snippets, I can get from state `ONE` to state `TWO` just fine, but the function `two` is bugged.

Firstly, you should see an error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`, where the traceback points you to the line

```
await update.message.reply_text("In two", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))
```

This is due to `InlineKeyboardMarkup` expecting a list of list of `InlineKyeboardButton` objects, not strings. Moreover, in `two` you're trying to call `update.callback_query.answer()`, but as `two` is a callback of a `MessageHandler`, `update.callback_query` will always be `None`.

---

### Edit

With the updated MWE, I get the following behavior:

- `/entry` -> bot replies with `entry_bla` as expected
- type any text -> bot replies with `yes. bla.` as expected
- type any text -> bot replies with `two_bla`. The second message with the attached keyboard is not send, because thes `InlineKeyboardButtons` are initialized wrongly - exactly one of the optional arguments must be passed. So the example get's stuck in state `TWO` and replies `two_bla` to any text message

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: I fixed the keyboard, and removed usage of callback_query from `two`, but still the transition doesn't work.
Can you please review my edited question? I added more details at the bottom

Comment: Can you provide a full minimal working example so that I can actually review your code?

Comment: Sure, I added a minimal example where transitions are not working

Comment: ran the example and edited my answer